# Stack Navigator issue while loading in React Native

Tags: react-native

**About**

Version of Stack Navigation - @react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3"

I am trying to show the home screen on load.

**Error Details**

[image]

**Code in App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import NavigationContainer from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from './screens/home';

export default function App() {

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </View>
    );
}
```

**Code in Home screen**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function Home() {

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

**Versions**

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
"expo": "~39.0.2",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `<MyStack />`  with the `NavigationContainer` tags

```
import {
  NavigationContainer,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

<NavigationContainer>
<MyStack />
</NavigationContainer>
```

As per the package.json you are using two versions of navigation so update all to navigation 5 something like below

```
 "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.0",
```

Comment: Please check my update in question. I am still facing same issue.

Comment: You should have only one navigation container as the root remove one

Comment: I meant, I tried both ways but still facing same problem, I have updated code now, Please check

Comment: What is the version of @react-navigation/native?

Comment: @Pankaj this generally happens when you mix up versions so check whether you are using version 5.xx for all packages

Comment: change this "react-navigation": "^4.4.2" to version     "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.0",

Comment: thats the issue actually update to version 5 an do an npm install then all good :)

Comment: latest is 5.7.6 as of date

Comment: Can you please check the question again? I update the error details with code and installed package version.

Comment: your import is wrong it should be import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

Comment: Yes, You are right. I am following this one now: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started, this time, no error message and title was saying undefined. Why so? Screen is blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223358/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-pankaj).

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

1. Stack navigator should be `<NavigationContainer>`'s immediate child.
2. If your React version does not support hooks use older version of react navigation.

Comment: Please check my update in question. I am still facing same issue.

Comment: Updated my answer too. :)